# uikit parallax: why background-size is being altered?

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, getuikit

I am trying to use ulkit's parallax UI to have a parallax background-image. However, for some reason, ulkit is making a background-size larger than my background-image.
I simply added `data-uk-parallax="{bg:'-200'}"`, my background image size is 1440*700, the container's width is 1920px, but ulkit is adding an inline style `background-size:21xxpx 15xxpx`.

Even in the demo page, in the first example, the background image's original size is 800*400, container's width is 822.75px, but ulkit is adding `background-size:1223px 612px` to the container, why is this? And is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

From my brief usage of the parallax component I found it very difficult to control the size & positioning of the parallax image. Especially when trying to make the image position look good responsively on mobiles, iPads & desktops.

My understanding was that the image needs to be rescaled to ensure that the background image always reaches to all 4 edges (top, right, bottom & left) of the container. This is to prevent the image scrolling off to white space.

The issue comes when you have the parallax set high (as opposed to a smaller value for a more subtle effect). This means that the image is massively scaled to ensure it never exceeds its container boundaries.

Potential solutions that I tried were:

- Alter the image's proportions to be squarer or more rectangular (depending on your container's proportions) so that the rescale is less extreme. Wide, thin banner-style parallax image's particularly benefit from this.
- Reduce the `bg` value (e.g. `"{bg : '-100'}"`) so the parallax effect is less extreme. This means that less rescale is needed to ensure the image fits all 4 boundaries when scrolling.
- Change the `viewport` value (e.g. `"{viewport : '0.5'}"`) so that the scroll area is more localised and therefore less image rescale is needed. This is useful when the image is at the very top or bottom of the page so the  parallax effect begins/ends immediately.
- If, like me, you needed a high `bg` value, then speeding up the `velocity` value (e.g. `"{velocity : '0.2'}"`) & reducing the `bg` value gives the effect of a more pronounced parallax by making the animation happen "sooner". This means that less image rescaling is needed.

Ultimately the solution for me required experimenting (a lot) with a combination of the above options to find a happy balance!

Hope that helps & wasn't too late :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
background-size: cover !important;
```

It's working for me ;)